# Service keeps deleting global object

Tags: angular6

I have a service that defines an object to be shared across multiple components. I'm setting this object's values in a function that is called during the APP_INITIALIZER and it seems to be ok at first, but when i try to get this object from other components, it's always empty...

In my data.service.ts i have this:

```
  // Object to be shared across components
  private loggedUser = {};

  setObject(user) {
    this.loggedUser = user;
  }

  getObject() {
    return this.loggedUser;
  } 

 // Function that is correctly executed during the APP_INITIALIZER
  Init() {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.getCurrentUser().subscribe((data: any) => {
       // I receive an object with some properties here
        this.setObject(data);
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
```

Then in one of my components i try to get this object with:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    var user = this.dataService.getObject();
    console.log(user); // It's always empty
  }
```

**EDITED:**

In my app.module.ts i have a factory that will receive the promise from Init() function:

```
export function initializeApp1(appInitService: DataService) {
  return (): Promise<any> => { 
    return appInitService.Init();
  }
}

providers: [ DataService, { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeApp1, deps: [DataService], multi: true} ],
```

As you can see, my goal is to set an object during the APP_INITIALIZER and being able to share it across components after that.

Comment: where is Init() called, tto whom it return the promise?

Comment: Updated the question, see the Edited section.